# Create Django named URL using template variable?

Tags: django, django-templates

How do you specify a named URL pattern in Django if you need to pass it a template variable?  My template contains the following URL:

```
# templates/welcome.html
# Link to template that shows all members near member with this uid
<a href="{% url 'show-members-near' %}uid={{ uid }}">Show members near you</a>
```

My top-level URLconf file contains the following pattern which points
to the application-specific url file:

```
# conf/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    url(r'^members/',            include('apps.members.urls')),
    ...
)
```

Here is my application-specific url file:

```
# app/members/url.py
url(r'^near/(?P<uid>\d{1,})/$',
    'show_members',
    {'template': 'show_members.html'},
    name='show-members-near'),
```

This is the error I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /personal_profile/welcome/
Reverse for 'show-members-near' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.  1 pattern(s) tried: ['members/near/(?P<uid>\\d{1})/$']
```

I tried to insert a keyword argument like this but it didn't work:

```
<a href="{% url 'show-members-near' uid={{ uid }} %}">Show members near you</a>
```

After doing some research, everything I read seemed to indicate that the keyword argument should be passed the way I did it up above.  What I'm trying to do is the equivalent of the following which *does* work:

```
<a href="/members/near/{{ uid }}/">See who's here</a>
```

How do I specify a keyword argument?  I didn't see anything that addresses this situation in the Django docs (although I might have missed it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd just pass the uid in as a keyword.  You can find it documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).  So, your url call would look like the following:

```
<a href="{% url 'show-members-near' uid=uid %}">Show members near you</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This case is, of course, explicitly supported and documented. You're missing the fact that everything inside a template tag is evaluated. You can just pass the uid in:

```
{% url 'show-members-near' uid=uid %}
```